# How about adding a "Check List" for Every New AU User who asks a Question?

Tags: discussion, users

One of the common thing in new AU Users is that they tend to post a question without doing a bit of research, How about adding a Checklist for new users with Reputation less than 'xy' like....

1. {X} Have you Googled It?
2. {X} Have you searched AU thorougghly for Questions Similar to that of yours?
3. {X} Have you tried finding out if your problem is a Bug?
4. {X} Are you sure your Question is not a Know-How previously discussed in Forum or AU.

   Implementing the above can (hopefully) decrease Duplication of Questions, coz Users (like me-in past) tend to be too lazy to do all those Mentioned above.

Comment: We already kind of have this :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think we have a duplicate problem per se, the problem is more that we don't have enough people with enough reputation to close duplicates quickly enough and people start  putting answers in the duplicate instead of the original question.

1. Recommending people to google things doesn't always work as there's a ton of information out there, which in many cases is incorrect. I would never send a friend to google, I would send them here, though we're now starting to have decent rankings in google so this is becoming less of a problem.
2. The site automatically does this for people when they ask a question. If they don't then we can easily mark it as a duplicate, this strengthens the ability for people to find a question. If someone is too lazy to do a search it's not a problem.
3. Most people don't know how to do this or might not know the difference between a software flaw or they don't know how to use it.
4. Same as answer #2.

So, long story short, if you see something that is a duplicate, flag it so we can dupe it.